# Execute python scripts from bash file via crontab

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron

**Set-up**

I have 2 simple python 3.x files on my desktop:

1) `cronjob_test.py`

```
#!Applications/anaconda/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os 
os.makedirs('/Users/myself/Desktop/TESTFOLDER')
```

2) `cronjob_test_copy.py`

```
#!Applications/anaconda/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os 
os.makedirs('/Users/myself/Desktop/TESTFOLDER2')
```

Both `.py` are executed via bashfile `A`,

```
#!/bin/bash  

cd /Users/myself/Desktop
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

/Applications/anaconda/bin/python cronjob_test.py
/Applications/anaconda/bin/python cronjob_test_copy.py
```

---

**Problem**

When I execute bash file `A` from the MacOSX Terminal, everything works fine: I end up with the 2 folders on my desktop.

However, when I try to execute `A` from crontab, nothing happens.

My crontab command is,

`25 15 * * * cd /Users/myself/Desktop ** bash A`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your crontab should have `&&` rather than `**`.

Comment: pfff. Sigh. Thanks!

Comment: To debug cron issues, add this at the end of your line `>/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2`.  Then you will see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.